# Step By Step Process for creating and distributing Mac App for beta testing

Tags: xcode, testing, mac-app-store

Can anyone provide a step by step guide for building and distributing a Mac App for beta testing.  The Mac App will be using iCloud.  I can't find any useful guide that works for me but here is what I have figured out so far:

1. Sign up to Developer Program (Dev Center)
2. Create a Developer Certificate (Dev Center)
3. Create an App ID (Dev Center)
4. Create development Devices (Dev Center)
5. Create Application Development Provisioning Profile for the app and selected test devices (Dev Center)
6. Install Developer Certificate on development Mac (Keychain)
7. Install Development Provisioning Profile on Mac (keyChain)
8. Install Provisioning Profiles into Xcode (drag and drop or import from Organiser)
9. Create an Archive of the App (using Xcode)
10. Export a Developer Signed Application (XCode Organiser)
11. Create Test User (iTunes Connect)
12. Copy the signed application to test device
13. Run the signed application - HERE I GET AN ERROR IN CONSOLE saying the following:

application was killed because 31/07/13 2:34:40.177 PM taskgated[21510]: killed xx.xxx.xxx.APPNAME[pid 22396] because its use of the com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers entitlement is not allowed

So somewhere I am doing something wrong... So some questions:

1. Is the iTunes Test User a whole new Apple ID ?  If so then I presume this user must be logged in on the test device in order for the App to create and use iCloud resources.
2. Is it possible to distribute the app for testing to an existing iCloud user ?  If so can i just skip the step about creating test users?
3. What have I missed out to allow the signed application to run in the test Mac and use iCloud ?  I was under the impression from the Apple docs that GateKeeper would allow Developer ID signed applications to run.

Thanks

Comment: Well some progress here. If I select Export As -> Application (in Organizer) and then select the Developer ID associated with the required Test Provisioning Profile the app will not launch and run correctly with access to iCloud. Yet to test on another standalone Mac though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out Beta testing does not use the production provisioning profile, it just uses the same development provisioning profile which has to be loaded onto the test device (if its a Mac).  My mistake thinking the production profile was used.

Comment: In iOS if you are you using testflight it will use production environment. But in the Mac only use sandbox enviroment for some reason